# how can i fuzzify the load_power vector?

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I'm using the power flow algorithm from `http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34200-radial-power-flow`

I have a load_power vector which contains actual load powers. There is a projected increase in load power of 6% and maximum increase of 10% (so any load can be at 100%, 106% or 110% of the actual vector).

How can I fuzzify the load_power vector so that the program gives a fuzzy load flow?

I've considered looping with different values of the load power with subsequent changes in load power but this is impractical for large vector. (for a 33-bus system, there will be 3^33 runs) 
NB:(tic toc gave me a run time of approx 2.3 seconds for one run, so 3^33 should be taking me millions of years... T_T)

Comment: why wont you add white\brown\pink noise to it?

Comment: the output would still be crisp not fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add noise to your vector, here is a way to do it.

Suppose you want 50% chance to have 100%, 20% chance to have 110% and the rest at 106%

```
V = 100*ones(10,1); % Your load percentage
noiseIntensity = rand(size(V));
idx = noiseIntensity > 0.5 
V(idx) = V(idx) + 6; 
idx = noiseIntensity > 0.8 
V(idx) = V(idx) + 4;
```